# XBee Pro S1 - Nibo2 - receiving data does not work fluently

Tags: uart, xbee

I'm currently working on a c project, having an XBee Pro Series 1 on my pc, allowing me to send data to my nibo2 roboter, also having that xbee module attached.

Sending data from the nibo2 roboter to my pc works great and there is no kind of data loss.

Sending data from my pc to the nibo2 works not fine:
When I'm trying to send 16 Bytes at one point of time, only the first 8 Byte arrive at my nibo2. The second 8 Byte are lost. When i send the data split into 8 Bytes and send them with a time difference of maybe 1s - 2s, it works fine.

The maybe interesting things you should know about this, are listed here:

XBee Datasheet: http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_H.pdf

The used library for the roboter (using uart0): http://nibo.sourceforge.net/doc/html/

Does anyone have an idea or does someone know the problem? Is it a thing about configuring the xbee module? interrupt problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How have you configured the XBee modules?  Which firmware version?  What baudrate?  Are you using hardware flow control (CTS and RTS signals)?

Can you use the "Assemble Packet" button on Terminal tab of X-CTU on the PC to send the 16-byte packet and have it received properly?

Can the serial port of the NIBO2 handle 16 bytes in one request?  Does it work if you use a wired connection instead of wireless?